Where has the IstioOperator resource gone?
I have recently upgraded istio from v1.20.6, then v1.21.3 and finally to v1.22.1. All of the workloads continue to work as they did prior to the upgrades. Before the upgrades I could run the following and see the 2 IstioOperators that were installed:
kubectl get istiooperator -A 

NAMESPACE      NAME
officespace    installed-state-officespace-external-alb-gateway   
istio-system   installed-state

Now I have upgraded both of the operators for some reason I can no longer see either of these these resources.
When I run the same command, as below, the resources no longer seem to be there:
kubectl get istiooperator -A 

No resources found

Any ideas why?
